# Flutter - What are the cons of using setState() many times in the app?

Tags: flutter, state

Does anyone can explain me what are the consequences, cons, of using setState() a lot of times in the app?

I know that every time I call setState() the screen is rebuilded, but those widget that was already built, will they still be in the memory? how does it work?

Using setState isn't good when talking about performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Generally it is recommended that the setState method only be used to
>   wrap the actual changes to the state, not any computation that might
>   be associated with the change. For example, here a value used by the
>   build function is incremented, and then the change is written to disk,
>   but only the increment is wrapped in the setState:
>
> ```
> Future<void> _incrementCounter() async {
>   setState(() {
>     _counter++;
>   });
>   Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
>   final String dirName = directory.path;
>   await File('$dir/counter.txt').writeAsString('$_counter');
> }
> ```
>
> in Flutter it’s okay to rebuild parts of your UI from scratch instead of modifying it. Flutter is fast enough to do that, even on every frame if needed.

Flutter is declarative. This means that Flutter builds its user interface to reflect the current state of your app.

[“The rule of thumb is: Do whatever is less awkward.”](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/ephemeral-vs-app)

from [flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)